# E-Mail Workflow "Created By" Difficulties

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Using SharePoint 2013 and Designer 2013.

My workflow is supposed to trigger an e-mail to send to two people, the list administrator (me) and the person who created the item for the list.

When I test the list by creating a new item, I get both e-mails, the confirmation one sent to the "created by" and the notification to the administrator.

But when any other users create an item, neither e-mail gets sent.

- Each user (including me) has internal and external e-mail addresses
- Users are present in SharePoint and can be selected individually for e-mail

I've looked over a dozen other "e-mail not sending" questions on here
Note: I work for a nationwide organization, and our SharePoint server is not on-site, so I don't have direct access to the server to make any changes, however I do of course have local administrative rights.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your workflow for analysis?

Answer (score 2):

One cause I've seen for this to happen is a 2013 style workflow (running through workflow manager) will not start for a person who is secured to that site via an AD group. You might be able to pick their name because they have security elsewhere, but if their list/site access is buried in an AD group, workflow manager has troubles.Two ways to test this:
1. Make sure the other user is actually the site members group (or whatever group you're using for contribute permission).
2. Change the workflow to be 2010 style, if you can.